# Trouble Getting Tooltip Width Correct Using CSS

Tags: css, html, tooltip

I've looked at various solutions to this and can't seem to get anything to work. I hope I'm missing something simple. What I want is for a tooltip width to use only what is needed, then wrap when a max-width is reached.

Here's my CSS:

```
<style>
    .tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: steelblue;
        color: yellow;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: help;
    }
        .tooltip:before {
            content: '?';
        }

        .tooltip .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            max-width: 300px;
            background-color: black;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: left;
            border-radius: 6px;
            z-index: 10;
        }

        .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
            visibility: visible;
        }
</style>
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<div class="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltiptext">
        I want this to wrap only after 300 pixels.
    </div>
</div>
Blacklist
```

What happens is it always wraps to fit only the widest word, making the max-width setting meaningless. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to cram the tooltip inside a container with 20px width. It simply doesn't have any wiggle room!

For a solution, move the .tooltiptext out of the .tooltip. The CSS can mostly stay the same.

```css
   .tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: steelblue;
        color: yellow;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: help;
        overflow:visible;
    }
        .tooltip:before {
            content: '?';
        }

        .tooltip + .tooltiptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            max-width: 300px;
            background-color: black;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: left;
            border-radius: 6px;
            z-index: 10;
        }

        .tooltip:hover + .tooltiptext {
            visibility: visible;
        }
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
</div>
<div class="tooltiptext">
  I want this to wrap only after 300 pixels.
</div>
Blacklist
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had tried putting it outside but I didn't know how to get the CSS to work, the "+" being the key. Your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set a min-width as well:

```
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 100px;
        max-width: 300px;
        background-color: black;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: left;
        border-radius: 6px;
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gdL458jo/

Comment: With your solution, the tooltip is always 300px wide, no matter the content. The OP wants the tooltip to be as wide as its contents, up to a maximum of 300px.